# Cassandra filter with ordering query modeling

Tags: scala, cassandra

I am new to Cassandra and I am trying to model a table in Cassandra. My queries look like the following

```
Query #1: select * from TableA where Id = "123"
Query #2: select * from TableA where name="test" orderby startTime DESC
Query #3: select * from TableA where state="running" orderby startTime DESC
```

I have been able to build the table for Query #1 which looks like

```
    val tableAStatement = SchemaBuilder.createTable("tableA").ifNotExists.
    addPartitionKey(Id, DataType.uuid).
    addColumn(Name, DataType.text).
    addColumn(StartTime, DataType.timestamp).
    addColumn(EndTime, DataType.timestamp).
    addColumn(State, DataType.text)

    session.execute(tableAStatement)
```

but for Query#2 and 3, I have tried many different things but failed. Everytime, I get stuck in a different error from cassandra.

Considering the above queries, what would be the right table model? What is the right way to model such queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query #2: **select * from TableB where name="test"**

```
CREATE TABLE TableB (
    name text,
    start_time timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (text, start_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (start_time DESC)
```

Query #3: **select * from TableC where state="running"**

```
CREATE TABLE TableC (
    state text,
    start_time timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (state, start_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (start_time DESC)
```

In cassandra you model your tables around your queries. Data denormalization and duplication is wanted. Notice the clustering order - this way you can omit the "ordered by" in your query

Comment: Thank you. This was what I was looking for it.